# Limit the number of related records returned for each parent record when using eager loading in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have four tables: comics, genres, genre_comic, and chapters. I want to limit the number of chapters returned for each comic when using eager loading in Laravel. Right now, my code limits the total number of chapters returned instead of limiting the chapters returned per comic. I want to get the three latest chapters for each comic fetched. Here's my current code:

```
$latestUpdated = Comic::select('id', 'title', 'slug', 'img')
   ->with([
        'genres' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'slug');
        },
        'chapters'=> function ($query) {
            $query->select('komik_id', 'number', 'slug')
                  ->orderBy('number', 'asc')
                  ->limit(3);
        }
    ])
    ->latest('updated_at')
    ->get();
```

How can I modify this code to achieve my goal?

Here are the table relations for my project

```
class Komik extends Model {

     public function genres()
     {
          return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
     }

     public function chapters()
     {
          return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class);
     }
}
```

Comment: Laravel natively has issues using `limit()` within Eager Loading (`with()` clauses). But there's [`staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) that enables that functionality.

Comment: I got vulnerability message after install that package "Found 1 security vulnerability advisory affecting 1 package". is this package safe to use?

Comment: Depends on the severity of that vulnerability; I haven't used that package specifically, but `staudenmeir` has a lot of packages for Laravel. I personally have trusted them in the past, but you'll need to make the judgement call.